# Multiple javaScript libraries | Emerging standards - compare to C++

Tags: c++, javascript

It seems like there are many different styles to write JavaScript, in fact I've heard that JavaScript is an expressive language.

But the point of code is functionality (function) not expression (form).

Is there a library that will be adopted into the ECMA standard the way the STL and Boost Library were adopted in to the C++ standard?

Comment: Expressiveness is important in a language - otherwise we'd all be content to program in assembly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems unlikely. The free market is producing some very excellent libraries and those libraries have the advantage that there are no delays through standards bodies and there are NOT multiple somewhat incompatible implementations by different browsers - there is a single implementation that works nearly identically across multiple browsers.

Because there is a single implementation, there is no drive or particular benefit to push them into a standards body - in fact, they would probably decline and slow innovation if forced into standards bodies with only downside.

Further much of the point of these libraries is that a single implementation works across browsers so we NEVER want a standard to which multiple vendors implement.

We reserve that process for the much slower standards evolution where newer browsers add new features, some of which are experimental and some of which are new standards.  The jQuery-like libraries solve a completely different problem that would not be helped by the standards process.  Some good ideas from jQuery-like libraries may eventually make it into a standards process and become built-in features, but that will be years and years after they were first available in the 3rd-party library and could be considered an evolutionary process of good ideas getting standardized on and then built-in.  But, by then, the libraries will have moved onto the next set of functionality and will always be years ahead and will always be there to supply missing functionality to older browsers and to solve cross browser implementation issues.

Answer (score 1):

> But the point of code is functionality (function) not expression
>   (form).

This used to be true, but we are finding it evolve in contemporary solutions. First, HTML provides the form. JavaScript is the behavior layer. To that, expressive behavior is a large part of what is requested for rich web applications. In other words, rich and responsive interactions, are behavior; and being able to express them well is a key to the capacity of programmatic implementation. So, expressiveness.

In truth, this term 'expressive' is a synonym for the intangible quality of JS that is also called 'flexibility'. As a voluptuous term, that can mean anything to anyone, 'Expressiveness' has potential to uniquely identify this concept.

Which is a great segway to the first part of your question:

> It seems like there are many different styles to write JavaScript,

This is the result of that flexibility and expressiveness.
There are many styles of JS, and (with windows 8, Chrome OS) there will probably be many more.

To find your style: you will have to try a few flavors; it is like ice-cream.

Here is another TIP: the things that look like egyptian heiroglyphs (at first), eventually begin to turn into identifiable patterns. Picking these 'design patterns' out, gives you the ability to understand all styles of JavaScript.

Understanding why JS is flexible and expressive is an exciting journey worth taking.

Hope that helps.